# What's using my swap (Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, swap

I have an Ubuntu 8.04 server which is running a database and a bunch of Java application servers. Its memory configuration and usage is:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16456176   15930028     526148          0      81372    9674196
-/+ buffers/cache:    6174460   10281716
Swap:      1951888     366100    1585788
```

I noticed that swap goes up every afternoon, and is released some time at night. The demand is not the same on all days, and starts at different times. So it's pretty random, except for the fuzzy "afternoon-night" boundary.

Load on this machine varies during the day. It's very low between midnight and 6-7 AM, much higher (but stable) until 6-8 PM, then dropping gradually.

Now I have the following questions:

1. How can I see which processes are using swap?
2. Why does it prefer to swap out rather than take some memory from cache?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The swap usage patterns you describe don't sound surprising. They're consistent with some permanently-running processes having rarely-used pages. During the day, due to the high activity, the rarely-used pages are almost always in the swap. At night, there's more room for them in RAM.

You can get a glimpse of how much memory of various kinds each process is using in `top` or `htop`. Neither show swap usage by default, but both can be configured to (top: press `f` and switch on the `SWAP` column; htop: press <kbd>F2</kbd>, add the `NSWAP` column). You can get more information about a particular process with `cat /proc/12345/vmstat` where `12345` is the process ID. Note that “how much swap a program is using” is not completely well-defined, as some pages are shared by several processes.

There are two major kinds of competitors for RAM: process memory (which can be swapped out) and disk caches (which can be re-read from a file). There is no reason to always prioritize process memory over disk caches: it's better to swap out a rarely-used portion of process memory than keep reading a file into memory again and again. The figures you give, with about half (say 30%–70%) of the memory devoted to disk caches, is typical for systems that have a reasonable amount of RAM for the tasks they're supposed to do.

Comment: I can't find a `NSWAP` column (Ubuntu 16.04 :/ ).

Comment: @jjmontes It's been [removed](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/commit/be1700cf9479f4199bb3810db831da943691b8f7#diff-b3f037d6e92f574afdf6f2e364b87693). I don't know why.

Comment: The [htop FAQ](https://hisham.hm/htop/index.php?page=faq) states that the author doesn't believe it's possible to accurately report swap usage, and that top's metric is inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

On StackOverflow, there is already an excellent answer on your first question ("Which process is actually using swap?").

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7180078/1442301

In a nutshell, tools like `top` or `htop` does not provide accurate information at all about swap usage.  You should dive into the `/proc` folder (in the pseudo file `/proc/$PID/smaps`) to get more accurate information.

The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7180078/1442301) mentioned above contains a short shell script to get this information echoed in a nice way.

Answer (score 0):

Without polling and parsing the outputs of tools like `vmstat`, `free` and `top`, the best place to look might be crontabs of the root user or other users on the system. If the general load on the system spikes reliably at a certain time, chances are there is a process in cron that creates the need for resources. Otherwise you can always create a ghetto throwaway logging utility with the `script` utility, which just records everything that goes to the STDOUT.

So if I needed to do a one-off throwaway script to catch the output for later inspection, in one terminal I would type:

```
script /tmp/free.txt
```

and then

```
while (true); do date; free; sleep 30; done
```

and in another terminal

```
script /tmp/top.txt
```

and then

```
while (true); do date; top -n 1; sleep 30; done
```

and then the next morning, kill both `script` invocations and match the output of `top` and `free`

once again this is a ghetto approach but it sounds like you only need a one-off

you might also like to read [the ubuntu swap guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)

Answer (score 0):

With `htop v1.01`, I pressed "S" to add `NSWAP` column instead of "F2" (as Gilles suggested), then `Columns` > `Available Columns` >  and `F5` to add it.

[image]

Comment: I have htop 2.0.1 and I don't see the NSWAP option :(

Comment: @Adam The maintener doesn't want to show this column anymore due to no reliable way to get this information; see [Why doesn't htop feature a SWAP column, like top?](http://hisham.hm/htop/index.php?page=faq)